# How to model crack opening in OpenModelica?

Tags: openmodelica

I would like to model a crack type opening in OpenModelica (Please see the picture). The equation of crack and effective-leakage-area are different. Crack equation is defined based on its length (in m) and its width (in mm) according to CONTAM software manual. I was just wondering how to convert effective-leakage-area model to crack model. [image]